# Cannot re-declare function name

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to effectively echo the date every 1 second following a sleep(1)
However I get the error

> Cannot redeclare date();

Here is my function:

```
function date()
{
  echo date('d/m/Y - G:i a');
  sleep(1);
}
```

then on the page I've just got

```
<?php date();?>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: It's as the error message states, you cannot re-declare functions. `date` is a language level (i.e. built-in) function.

Comment: have changed the function name to showdate and it does now display the date however its not doing it every 1 second as specified

Comment: "as specified"...specified where? You've shown no code which would cause the function to be called repeatedly...and if you want to do that, you'll need to do it client-side, not server-side, unless you want your page to refresh every second (and I don't think your users will thank you for that).

Comment: ahh yeah good point..
just switched it over to jquery and its working as planned now
many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function named `date()` already exists, built in to PHP - see http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Therefore you can't re-use the name. You just need to give your function a different name (or place it within a class or namespace, and reference it as such).